# MEAN stack mongoose sending empty arrays

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

> I'm close to having a working web app. *Mongoose IS sending my data to
>   mongolab if I have it in a flat schema no problems*. When I try to
>   arrange it into something a bit more manageable it arrives as an empty
>   array(s). I've tried a few different schema designs with similar
>   results. I'm not doing anything overly fancy. I've looked at the other
>   posts on here to do with empty arrays but the only things I couldn't
>   figure out was when sending the data via submit() my XHR requests:

---

> RESOLVED

---

Before we start this might not work right off the bat for you as i'm doing all my exports differently with the mean stack. But the principle of how to embed an array should still work.

After a break and something to eat. I've update my original post to reflect my current code in the controller and in my schema. I'll show what it looks like in the db. For anyone else who wants to place an array within an array:

within the controller or where you'll be binding your form data to the document create an empty array, thus:

```
var followupDetails = [];
```

create an object to represent the data you want to embed ( array goes inside object )

```
        var followup = {
            followup: [{
                technicianName: this.technicianName,
                consultationStatus: this.consultationStatus,
                followUpDate: this.followUpDate,
                followUpNotes: this.followUpNotes,
                installDate: this.installDate,
                technicianCellPhone: this.technicianCellPhone
            }]
        };
```

push the object into the empty array, thus:

followupDetails.push(followup);

add the property to the existing object that you want to embed the array into. Mine was called **consult**, I created a **followup** property with the value of my the followupDetails array.

```
consult.followup = followupDetails;
```

you DON'T have to add this to the $scope.create function that creates your document, that will be passed through the schema. It is created when compiling it's parent. i.e.

```
var ConsultationSchema = new Schema({
    "consultation":{
        "customerDetails": [customerDetailsSchema],
        "currentSystem": [currentSystemSchema],
        // followups in now inside the consultDetails
        "consultDetails": [consultDetailSchema]
    }
});
```

everything else is exactly the same. Note also that my schema for consult where followups lives now looks same as before:

```
var consultDetailSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    ...
    followup:[followupSchema]
});
```

Here's the full schema I put together

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customerDetailsSchema = new Schema({
        "customerName": {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerAddress": {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerCity": {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerState": {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerZipCode": {
            type: Number,
            default: ' ',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerHomePhone": {
            type: Number,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerCellPhone": {
            type: Number,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "customerEmail": {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "comporiumId":{
        type:Number,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    }
});

var currentSystemSchema = new Schema({
        "systemType":{
            type:String,
            default:'',
            trim:true
        },
        "systemOther":{
            type: String,
            default: '',
            trim: true
        },
        "systemMonitored":{
            type:String,
            default:'',
            trim:true
        },
        "deluxePhonePackage": {
            type: Boolean
        }
});

var followupSchema = new Schema({
    "technicianName":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "consultationStatus":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "followUpDate":{
        type:Date,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "followUpNotes":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "installDate":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "technicianCellPhone":{
        type:Number,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    }
});

var consultDetailSchema = new Schema({
    "consultComments":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "consultantName":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "technician":{
        type:String,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "scheduleDate":{
        type:Date,
        default:'',
        trim:true
    },
    "created": {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    "user": {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    "followUpDetails": [followupSchema]
});


/**
 * Consultation Schema
 */
var ConsultationSchema = new Schema({
    "consultation":{
        "customerDetails": [customerDetailsSchema],
        "currentSystem": [currentSystemSchema],
        "consultDetails": [consultDetailSchema]
    }
});

mongoose.model('Consultation', ConsultationSchema);
```

Here the controller, remember when you hit submit it should run the create() function do the code that builds your document within the body of the create function just before you instantiate a new instance of the model:

```
'use strict';

// Consultations controller
angular.module('consultations')
    .controller('ConsultationsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Consultations',

    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Consultations) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        // Create new Consultation
        $scope.create = function() {

        var customerDetails = [];
        var systemDetails = [];
        var consultDetails = [];
        var followupDetails = [];

        var customer = {
            customerName: this.customerName,
            customerAddress: this.customerAddress,
            customerCity: this.customerCity,
            customerState: this.customerState,
            customerZipCode: this.customerZipCode,
            customerHomePhone: this.customerHomePhone,
            customerCellPhone: this.customerCellPhone,
            customerEmail: this.customerEmail,
            comporiumId: this.comporiumId
        };

        var system = {
            systemType: this.systemType,
            systemOther: this.systemOther,
            systemMonitored: this.systemMonitored,
            deluxePhonePackage: this.deluxePhonePackage
        };

        var followup = {
            followup: [{
                technicianName: this.technicianName,
                consultationStatus: this.consultationStatus,
                followUpDate: this.followUpDate,
                followUpNotes: this.followUpNotes,
                installDate: this.installDate,
                technicianCellPhone: this.technicianCellPhone
            }]
        };

        var consult = {
            consultComments: this.consultComments,
            consultantName: this.consultantName,
            technician: this.technician,
            scheduleDate: this.scheduleDate,
            created: this.created,
            user: this.user
        };

        customerDetails.push(customer);
        systemDetails.push(system);
        followupDetails.push(followup);
        consultDetails.push(consult);

        consult.followup = followupDetails;

            // Create new Consultation object
            var consultation = new Consultations ({
                consultation:{
                    customerDetails: customerDetails,
                    currentSystem: systemDetails,
                    consultDetails: consultDetails,
                }
            });
```

So here is what I was getting originally:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "556daad4da83801971345211"
    },
    "consultation": {
        "consultDetails": [],
        "currentSystem": [],
        "customerDetails": []
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And here's what it now looks like the in db not passing data because i'm just clicking create and not filling anything in:

```
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "556e479f9695f6c804de0a7f"
    },
    "consultation": {
        "consultDetails": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "556e479f9695f6c804de0a80"
                },
                "followup": [
                    {
                        "_id": {
                            "$oid": "556e479f9695f6c804de0a81"
                        },
                        "technicianCellPhone": null,
                        "installDate": "",
                        "followUpNotes": "",
                        "followUpDate": null,
                        "consultationStatus": "",
                        "technicianName": ""
                    }
                ],
                "created": {
                    "$date": "2015-06-03T00:17:35.233Z"
                },
                "scheduleDate": null,
                "technician": "",
                "consultantName": "",
                "consultComments": ""
            }
        ],
        "currentSystem": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "556e479f9695f6c804de0a82"
                },
                "systemMonitored": "",
                "systemOther": "",
                "systemType": ""
            }
        ],
        "customerDetails": [
            {
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "556e479f9695f6c804de0a83"
                },
                "comporiumId": null,
                "customerEmail": "",
                "customerCellPhone": null,
                "customerHomePhone": null,
                "customerZipCode": 0,
                "customerState": "",
                "customerCity": "",
                "customerAddress": "",
                "customerName": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: I did think early on that it might be something to do with how I was nesting the data. Admittedly I'm still a bit shaky on how it's being passed through the entire stack. But from all the examples I could find online, dropping arrays in like that seems legit.

Comment: Hi. You like reading indented and formatted data. So do we. Please consider this when submitting. Hopefully my edit here has been accepted soon if not by the time you read this. Thanks

Comment: Also. Please **edit** your question with additional information rather than leave comments

Comment: I tried, it failed to accept it twice. I'm starting to think how my data is bound in the controller is the issue if no one sees anything wrong this what I've posted already.

Comment: What's the actual data being sent by the browser? How are you trying to process the data? There's no array in the data you're sending, just a JSON object.

Comment: `"customerDetails": [customerDetailsSchema],` you told it to be an array. So, you'll have to add it as an array, or make it not an array.

Comment: And so "where is the code" that should be placing this in an array? GET does not "Create/Replace" ( See CRUD ) in any form of action. But your code might be doing something silly. But still it is not posted here.

Comment: So you're saying the issue is with how I am passing the data to mongoose? I figured as much,  I'm passing a flat object via the controller to mongoose. I wasn't quite sure how it was being interpreted by mongoose or "plugged into" the schema. That would explain why it's sending a JSON object. I had it working that way when testing some things out like I said before. Now I'm not quite sure how to format it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose doesn't magically convert one data format to your schema's format. You would need to do that yourself. It just enforces your schema on an object. Since none of your documents have a [required option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) and you aren't [strictly enforcing the schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict), you are essentially creating an empty document (by default empty suddoc arrays are returned).

So, you need to update whatever method is handling your post request to format the request post object into the correct form to match your Mongoose schema. You can also set the schema option `strict` to throw rather than ignore (the default) to ensure you aren't attempting to add an invalid property to the document. After that you should be able to retrieve a non empty document.

Comment: I've added an edit to show where I'm at now. Still having issues with seeing the data, and only followup is not getting nested into the db.

Comment: You are shifting your question from Mongoose to Angular. What does the raw post body look like now? Also what do you think `this` refers to in your controller?

Comment: This refers to the name of the object it's defined in? So the function? The wider name space of what is injected into the function?  this. autocompetes on this.customer* so I used this. And actually I'm pretty much keeping my question locked to "what am I doing wrong", hence.. help post on what appears from the outside to be a help forum? Something i'm starting to doubt more by the second  lol. Angular and mongoose are involved in getting my data to the database LeRz? Bigger picture mate. I don't mind being wrong. Don't keep me in suspense am using this wrong?  Did I ruin the ending?

Comment: Ah. No worries, `this` can be confusing for a lot of people (some who have been using JS for years). I would recommend reading [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) to get a better understanding of it. As far as your problem(s), I still would like to see what the raw post body looks like coming from Angular. `this` is most certainly not what you think it is and I would assume all of those values are almost certainly undefined.

Comment: Well to be honest, the this keyword is something I can figure out later this was an issue with nesting. I can't get the followups array block to nest within another array. I'll look over what you've send for the values issues.

Comment: Well logging this shows Constructor {}, and logging this.constructor shows function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Consultations)  which is most certainly what I think it is, I'm aware of the other properties that comes with this. I just believe them to be irrelevant to this question.  Those values are undefined yes, until I fill them in and hit submit I thought. If I figure it out I'll post the answer at the end of my original post.

Comment: I still think you might be surprised what `this` really is. :-D

Comment: I'm more surprised at your persistence that it wouldn't work, when now it does. I may have muddied 'exactly' what it is in my brief 2 sentence description. But I don't say something is worked previously if it didn't. You're the second person to tell me it wouldn't work though so don't fret. Post altered if you want to have a look.

Comment: I think we are drifting a bit off topic and I hope you aren't taking offense to my suggestion. Essentially `this` does not refer to the function but to the context of where the function is called at runtime. My point of trying to passively suggest this understanding is that while your code *may* work it might not work *how* you think it does. And for my time, I'd rather understand why something works rather than just getting it to work.